# How can I convert a Python file to a .exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

I've seen many options online, but none of them seem to support Python 3.8. Is there any way to convert a python project to a .exe anymore? If so, how can I do that?

EDIT:
I've tried PyInstaller multiple times, both before it was recommended here and afterwards, but I keep getting huge error messages that I don't know how to make sense of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a python 3.8 file to .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59134747/converting-a-python-3-8-file-to-exe)

Comment: I would suggest adding in what you tried and what errors you received. I can spin up a Windows VM and see what I can do myself and what method works for 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pyinstaller`.

Example: `pyinstaller yourfile.py -F --onefile`

This will turn your code into a `.exe` file on Windows.

To install PyInstaller, you simply use pip, thus `pip install PyInstaller` or `pip3 install PyInstaller`.

You can also make sure you have the latest development version of pyinstaller: `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz`

Comment: I tried this, and all it did was give me a whole bunch of errors.

```
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "c:\python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, re, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
  File "c:\python38\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.
```

Comment: @TMayer The essence of stack overflow is delving into resolving those errors at that level, not at the high level "solve this for me" level, it is about "I tried x and it resulted in y, when I wanted it to result in z" then go from there. I would suggest rewording the question and add in what you tried.

Comment: @TMayer looks like you can try `pip install enum` or similar as a pre-req. This also looks like it might be some BS related to PyCharm or other IDE setting paths and screwing up versions.

Comment: @TMayer also may be worth trying the dev build of pyinstaller that should work with 3.8: `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz

` based on convo here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4311#issuecomment-688532918

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: I tried both of those, and both of them still resulted in errors. When I tried to run the pyinstaller command I got the `AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'` error again. Can you help me understand why that's happening?

Comment: @TMayer can you try this: `pip3 uninstall enum34` based on thread here: https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/1582#issuecomment-461257304

Comment: Actually, I just found out the cause of that enum error, I just had to uninstall enum34. I was able to make a .exe file from my code, but when I run it I get an Import Error in line 1 that doesn't give me anything useful.

Comment: @TMayer Ok so I would mark my answer as correct when you can and then open another question with that as an issue. Since you successfully created a .exe. I upvoted your question, not sure why it was downvoted.